# Apex Oracle SQL : How to get Date Picker to from last day to today, and from sunday - monday?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Little more information:

On dashboard, we have queries that are set up where it bases the results based on 2 date pickers. The first date picker is from: (Date) and the second is to: (Date).

Currently, have dynamic action to set it from date to sysdate - 1, and that works great for tuesday-friday. However, when it's a monday morning, I want it to be able to set the from date to the last friday, and to date is simply sysdate.

Is this possible to do and how would I go about doing that? Currently on mondays we just have to manually change the date to last friday, which isn't too huge of a deal, but when we open 20+ pages it makes it a hassle.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you already have dynamic action which sets `FROM` and `TO` dates, modify it so that it checks whether "today" (i.e. date returned by `sysdate`) is Monday or not.

If it is, find **next** Friday (with the `next_day` function) and subtract 7 to get **previous** Friday. If not, use *yesterday*.

This is code that does the calculation:

```
select case when to_char(sysdate, 'DY') = 'MON' then
                 trunc(next_day(sysdate, 'FRI')) - 7
            else 
                 trunc(sysdate) - 1
       end as from_date
from dual;
```